# Different in and out curve for animated opacity widget flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have code below , a AnimatedOpacity widget with animation curve Curves.elasticIn.
That curve used in both opacity 1 to 0 and 0 to 1.How i can use `two different curve` for opacity 1 to 0 and 0 to 1. ?

```
AnimatedOpacity(
    opacity: _trueOrFalse? 1.0 : 0.0,
    curve: Curves.elasticIn,
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
    child: Center(
    child: SvgPicture.asset("assets/....svg"),
    ),
```

Comment: Can you do something like `_trueOrFalse? curve1 : curve2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it as you have done with opacity.

```
AnimatedOpacity(
    opacity: _trueOrFalse? 1.0 : 0.0,

    *//if opacity is 1.0 then use elasticIn Curve else use elasticOut for 0.0 opacity*
    curve: _trueOrFalse? Curves.elasticIn: Curves.elasticOut,

    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
    child: Center(
    child: SvgPicture.asset("assets/....svg"),
    ),
```